# How to get a get parameter in Struts 2?

Tags: parameters, struts2

In my result jsp page(view), how do I access a get parameter ?

I tried:

```
<%

    String para = request.getParameter('whatever');


%>
```

but it didn't work.

I know that I can use  but...I like to get the value in jsp code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should, if it's an actual parameter of the current request. Although you'd need to use double-quotes, since you're writing Java code.

But why would you want to do this?

Comment: // Thank you for the answer. I will try again. ah! haha..yes...old habit. I'm just trying out Struts2..

Comment: I think that Dave's question on why would you do this was meant in the context of, "Why would you use scriptlet notation instead of struts tags?" If you're using struts, parameters from your actions are available through standard struts tags, your parameter for instance would be accessible from <s:property value="whatever" />

Comment: Only if the user had a setWhatever/getWhatever method on the action. JSTL would work for getting at request parameters, too.